# How do I perform an operation only when two variables are not None without copying them?

Tags: rust

I want to perform an operation if and only if `a` and `b` are not `None`. I do not want create a copy of complex structures, which is why `struct X` does not implement `Clone`.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct X {
    d: u32,
}

struct Foo {
    a: Option<X>,
    b: Option<u32>,
    c: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let smart_ptr = Arc::new(Mutex::new(RefCell::new(Foo {
        a: Some(X { d: 1 }),
        b: Some(2),
        c: 3,
    })));

    {
        let lock = smart_ptr.lock().unwrap();
        let foo = lock.borrow();
        if let (Some(ref a), Some(b)) = (foo.a, foo.b) {
            println!("a: {:?}, b: {}", a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to compile this code, I get:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:25:42
   |
25 |         if let (Some(ref a), Some(b)) = (foo.a, foo.b) {
   |                                          ^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How should I fix the `if` statement to get what I want without compilation errors?

Comment: Please take the time to create a [MCVE]. You don't need approximately half of the code shown ([for example](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=3e6b0bef5db6a1732494a16f01de2c3d&version=stable))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the `if let` statement to only reference `a` and `b` to `foo.a` and `foo.b`, otherwise `if let` would move some parts out of the borrowed value. This is forbidden for two reasons:

1. The reference is immutable, so it can not be changed.
2. References are always guaranteed to point to completely valid objects. If you could move `foo.a` into `a`, "stealing away" the struct from your lender, then the value residing in `foo.a` would no longer be valid, making `foo` also invalid.

One solution would be to duplicate the values `Foo::a` and `Foo::b` via `clone()` which is - as you noted - unneeded and performance wise not optimal, especially since it would mean a deep copy.

I got it working without copying:

```
if let (&Some(ref a), &Some(b)) = (&foo.a, &foo.b) {
    println!("a: {:?}, b: {}", a, b);
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster, thanks. It has more meat to the bone now. Only thing that's still unclear to me is why `foo.a` would be invalid. Invalid in what sense? Pointing to a "unprotected heap memory" block?

Comment: Pointing to a piece of allocated memory on the heap is a straightforward problem, yes. Ownership of that value controls who frees the memory, and a double free would be a problem. However, there's nothing special about the heap here. For example, if you have a `MutexGuard` or a `File` or anything that performs actions when dropped, "duplicating" ownership would be a *bad* thing.

Answer (score 5):

Using a smaller example:

```
struct Foo {
    a: Option<String>,
    b: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = &Foo {
        a: Some("hi".into()),
        b: Some("world".into()),
    };

    if let (Some(a), Some(b)) = (foo.a, foo.b) {
        println!("a: {}, b: {}", a, b);
    }
}
```

You can use [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) to perform the same type of matching on a reference as [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41387614/155423):

```
if let (Some(a), Some(b)) = (foo.a.as_ref(), foo.b.as_ref()) {
    println!("a: {}, b: {}", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [destructure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/patterns.html#destructuring) `Foo` instead of creating a tuple:

```
if let Foo { a: Some(ref a), b: Some(b), .. } = *foo {
    println!("a: {:?}, b: {}", a, b);
}
```